# Why Remote Desktop Sessions show client internal IP address?

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, rdp

I have Windows Server 2008 r2 with static ip address on WAN interface.
I connecting to the server from home from my laptop. Laptop at home is behind nat box.
When i connecting to the server from home in Remote Desktop Session Manager i see in client status dialog a local ip address of client behind the nat box not WAN ip address of nat box.
I suppose i must see the WAN ip address of the nat box in Remote Desktop Session Manager, isnt it?

Comment: It's really not clear what you're asking here, but I'm guessing you're wondering why the client IP is showing your laptop's internal address and not your router's WAN address? Do you have a VPN tunnel between your home machine and the server? If so, there's your answer.

Answer (score 1):

Your using the Remote Desktop Client on your home PC, so the values you see in RDS Manager (IP and hostname) are that of the computer running RDC, which is your internal IP and real computer name at home.

Comment: Correct, I was going to point out that you get the computer name as well. Fwiw the internal IP is much better, as when you have 25 users from the same external network on your server it's good info to have when troubleshooting with the other sites remote tech.

Comment: This is by design as Terminal Services was originally designed to allow a central system to be used from remote locations and was created for the corporate world, where we need to be able to identify the machine, not just the network.